# Getting the error "$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;" in share-point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-addin

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I have create a visual web part in vs 2013. I have deployed and try to add the .webpart to my SharePoint 2013 team site.
When I try to add the .webpart then I am getting the below error:-

```
$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;
```

Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me whilst I was trying to debug my WebPart from Visual Studio, always after the 'first' debug session it failed to re-load and thus, threw `$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;` when launching the 2nd debug session.

Finally I found what worked for me was:

`Visual Studio -> Build -> Select 'Retract'`

Upon doing so, I was able to Clean the solution, re-deploy and then finally start debugging as normal.

I know it's quite a small thing, but other resources on the web was also suggesting to:

- Add Guid Attribute to the WebPart (To make sure there's no mis-match)
- Rename the WebPart to .wsp
- Restart Visual Studio and the debugging browser all together (With Admin rights too!)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue when trying to add my custom webpart to the page. There was no error reported in deployment of wsp as well .

What i did ?
I removed the existing wsp and redeployed it again with wsp from my rebuilt vs2010 solution .

Though the issue was resolved i am not sure why this happened as i couldn't investigate further.

Comment: I have same problem in sharepoint 2013. Problem was in Project targer framework.
just recreate VS project in .NET framework 4.0 help's me to solve that

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake .webpart for WebPart property initialization 
**BadString**

Resolved the error by changing **BadString** to a number: 
8

Answer (score 1):

My solution was changing the propertys of my project:

Sandboxed Solution from **true** to **false**

Include Assembly In Package from **false** to **true**

When I created my project I selected the false propertys. In my first test WebPart I did it correctly so I could figure out my problem.

Answer (score 1):

On the project you just need to set "Include Assembly In Package" to "True"